# QWater Model - Analysis Interpretation

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, water

[image]I want to ask about QWater plugin function in QGIS output, how can I understand on what the p and H stands for? Also what does the negative and positive value indicates to?

Currently I just create shapefile by myself without any real data to be use for this QWater plugin.